# What syntax will check if a variable name containing spaces is defined?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

Windows user defined environment variable names can contain any character except `=`.

Special characters can be included by escaping them. A simpler method is to simply enclose the entire SET expression within quotes. For example:

```
set "A weird & "complex" variable=My value"
set A weird ^& "complex" variable=My value
```

Both expressions above give the same result. The variable name is **`A weird & "complex" variable`** and the value is **`My value`**

The IF DEFINED construct is used to test if a variable is defined. Quotes don't work for this test, special characters in the name (including quotes) must be escaped.

```
set "A&B=value"
if defined A^&B echo This works
if defined "A&B" echo This does not work
```

The above escaped test works just fine. The quoted test does not work

But how can I test if a variable containing spaces exists?

```
set "A B=value"
if defined A^ B echo this does not work!
```

It seems like the above should work, but it doesn't!

I'm looking for an answer that does NOT involve expanding the variable using %A B% or !A B!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interessting question (I love this syntax base questions).

Obviously you know how to check it with delayed expansion and also FOR-parameters works.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "AAA BBB=value"
set ""AAA BBB"="
set "AAA="
for %%a in ("AAA BBB") do if defined %%~a echo FOR: This works

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "varname=AAA BBB"
if defined !varname! echo Delayed: This works

if defined %varname% ( echo percent: Never comes here 
) ELSE ( echo percent: Never comes here ? )

if defined AAA^ BBB ( echo escape1: Never comes here
) ELSE ( echo escape1: fails )

set AAA=Hello
if defined AAA^ BBB ( 
   echo escape2: It only test for AAA the BBB will be "removed"
) ELSE ( echo escape2: fails )

set "space= "
if defined AAA!space!BBB echo inject space: This works

if defined "AAA BBB"  (echo Quote1: Never comes here 
) ELSE ( echo Quote1: Fails )

set ""AAA BBB"=value"
if defined "AAA BBB" echo Quote2: This works, it checks for "AAA BBB" with quotes
```

In my opionion, in the *escape2* example the parser first split the line into tokens this way:
`<if> <defined> <AAA BBB> <echo ....`
But at the execution time of the *if defined* it rescan the `<AAA BBB>` token so it only gets the `AAA`.
You can't inject a second escape like `AAA^^^ BBB` as this only searches for the variable named `AAA^`

I can't see a solution without delaying/FOR, as the escaping of the space always fails.

**EDIT: It can also be solved with `SET <varname>`**
The solution of ijprest uses the SET command to test the variable without the need of escaping the varname.
But it also shows interessting behaviour with spaces inside and at the end of a varname.

It seems to follow these rules:
`SET varname` searches for all variables beginning with varname, but first it removes all characters after the last space character of varname, and it removes all leading spaces.
So you can't search for variables with beginning with space (but it is also a bit tricky to create such a varname).

The same behaviour is also active if the variablename is enclosed into quotes, but then exists one more rule.
First remove all characters after the last quote, if there are at least two quotes.
Use the text inside of the quotes, and use the "space"-rule.

Sample.

```
set    "   abc def ghi"  junk junk
*** 1. removes the junk 
set    "   abc def ghi"
*** 2. removes the quotes
set       abc def ghi
*** 3. removes all after the last space, and the trailing spaces
set abc def
*** Search all variables beginning with abc def
```

Comment: The FOR/!delay! solution wasn't obvious when I needed sleep. I thought of it when I woke up, but you already had an excellent answer posted! :)

Comment: Your *escape2* analysis is very interesting. Yet another opportunity to inject a comment into a statement

Answer (score 3):

I also love this sort of question!  :)

Here's another possible solution I came up with... using SET itself to test the existence, and using the ERRORLEVEL result:

```
set "A B=foo"
set A B >nul 2>nul&& echo 1. This works
set "A B ">nul 2>nul&& echo 2. This works

set "A weird & "complex" variable=foo"
set A weird ^& "complex" variable >nul 2>nul&& echo 3. This works
set "A weird & "complex" variable ">nul 2>nul&& echo 4. This works
```

Note that this only works if your variables are *unique* in the sense that no variable name is the prefix of another one.  Otherwise you risk false positives, as SET's default behavior is to show all variables that start with the parameter you pass.  If this could be the case, you could filter the results with findstr:

```
set "A B="
set "A B C=foo"
set "A B ">nul 2>nul&& echo 5. Failed (false positive)
set "A B "|findstr /B /L /C:"A B=" >nul||echo 6. This works (no false positive)
```

Also, the *single* trailing space after the variable name seems to be required.  Without it, SET often mis-parses the input. Bizarrely, if you add an extra space between the "2>nul" and "&&" in case #3 it stops working (unless you remove the space before ">nul")... weird.

Comment: +1 Good solution with the addition of FINDSTR. I had thought of the SET test and rejected it, but didn't think to add FINDSTR. I still prefer jeb's solution because it doesn't require pipe or external command, so it is faster.

Comment: Very interesting discovery about extra space required else any variable starting with "a" matches. The quotes aren't needed. `set a<space>b` fails. `set a<space>b<space>` works. `set a<space>b<space><space>` fails! @jeb - any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: I add a comment into my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8257295/463115) about the SET-space behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to reassign it to another variable (one without spaces) and test *that*. See here:

```
rem Prepare ONLY variable 'a b'
set "a b=123"
echo [a b]=%a b%

rem This will ouput: [a b] is defined
set var=%a b%
if defined var (
  echo [a b] is defined
) else (
  echo [a b] is not defined
)

rem This will output: [c d] is not defined
set var=%c d%
if defined var (
  echo [c d] is defined
) else (
  echo [c d] is not defined
)
```

Comment: Of course that works, but the last requirement of my original question stated I was looking for an answer that did NOT use %A B% or !A B!. (BTW, assigning !A B! is much safer. The assignment of %A B% can fail depending on the contents)

Answer (score -2):

I do it by defining a flag as TRUE if needed...

```
rem /* sample code */
set VAR_SET=
if <some condition> set VAR_SET=TRUE&set VAR=this data has spaces

rem /* test for VAR_SET using 'if defined' */
if defined VAR_SET (
  rem /* do something with the other data in the variable %VAR% */
)

rem /* clear the flag */
set VAR_SET=
```

Comment: You haven't answered the question - you completely missed the point.