# find gpo's in gpresult (for/find/findstr)

Tags: variables, for-loop, find, set, findstr

I wan't some specific rules for different gpo's, if I use: "gpresult /r /scope user" I get to see which GPO's (security groups) are active. Now how can I filter some of these active GPO's to my batch file?
This is part of the outcome from my gpresult:

```
De gebruiker is lid van de volgende beveiligingsgroepen
      Domain Users
      Iedereen
      SophosAdministrator
      SophosUser
      BUILTIN\Administrators
      Gebruikers
      INTERACTIEF
      AANMELDEN OP DE CONSOLE
      Geverifieerde gebruikers
      Deze organisatie
      LOKAAL
      Iedereen
      GS_08_cv's
      Tekenkamer
      GS_03_verslagen_openbaar
      GS_07_overeenkomsten
      GS_01_facturen
      GS_04_Functieprofielen
      GS_00_documenten
      AEC
      GS_02_functioneringsgesprekken
      GS_06_offertes
      GS_05_Arbeidsovereenkomsten
      GS_09_ aanbevelingsbrieven
      GS_03_verslagen_beperkt
      Systeembeheer
      Hoog verplicht niveau
```

I know I can search for a specific name (string?) with findstr, **i.e.**

```
gpresult /r /scope user | findstr /L /i "SysteemBeheer" > nul 2>&1
REM *alternative* gpresult /r /scope user | FIND /i "SysteemBeheer" > nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (ECHO Sys.Beheer) ELSE ECHO NO.sys.beheer
```

But how can I change it so multiple lines being read?

**i.e.** (borrowed some code just for example)

```
systeminfo | find "Microsoft Windows" > %TEMP%\osname.txt
FOR /F "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i IN (%TEMP%\osname.txt) DO set vers=%%i

echo %vers% | find "Windows 7" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_7

echo %vers% | find "Windows Server 2008" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_2008

echo %vers% | find "Windows Vista" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_vista

goto warnthenexit
```

I mean this does search for multiple variables I hope to some how find multiple Security Groups (GPO's) from the gpresult function (or perhaps a better way?)

I'd like it to do something like this, *if systeembeheer exist do blaat1***,** *if aec exist do blaat2***,** *if tekenkamer exist do blaat3***,** BUT multiple GPO's can exists SO the script/search must not stop if 1 of the above does exist, it still has to look if one of the others also exist.

***Perhaps a little more like this?

```
@echo off
CLS
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (systeembeheer tekenkamer aec) do (
    gpresult /r /scope user | findstr /L /i %%i
    if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo %%i ok process found !errorlevel!
    if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo %%i no process found !errorlevel!
)

:exit
pause
```

**AND changed it a litte:**

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%i in (SysteemBeheer Administratie PersoneelsZaken TeamPlan) do (
    gpresult /r /scope user | findstr /L /i %%i > nul 2>&1
    if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 Set "GPO_%%i=True"
    if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 Set "GPO_%%i=False"
REM if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo %%i ok process found !errorlevel! *debug lines*
REM if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo %%i no process found !errorlevel! *debug lines*
)

if "%GPO_systeemBeheer%" == "True" (Echo GPO_SysteemBeheer=%GPO_systeemBeheer%) else Echo GPO_SysteemBeheer Not Found!
if "%GPO_Administratie%" == "True" (Echo GPO_Administratie=%GPO_Administratie%) else Echo GPO_Administratie Not Found!
if "%GPO_PersoneelsZaken%" == "True" (Echo GPO_PersoneelsZaken=%GPO_PersoneelsZaken%) else Echo GPO_PersoneelsZaken Not Found!
if "%GPO_TeamPlan%" == "True" (Echo GPO_TeamPlan=%GPO_TeamPlan%) else Echo GPO_TeamPlan Not Found!

:exit
echo.
echo.
PAUSE
```

This does seem to do what I want, bu i'm not sure if it's the best way or the right way to do it ???

Comment: Does anyone know if the last piece of script is the best way to do it, or is there a better / more efficient way perhaps?

Comment: is this the bast and/or only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how I missed this question before - better late then never I hope :-)

Your basic strategy is sound. There are a few things you can do to improve and/or simplify.

The GPRESULT command takes significant time to execute. I would capture the results in a file once and then search the file. That should improve performance.

When defining a "boolean" variable, it is easier to undefine the variable for FALSE, and set the value to anything to represent TRUE. (I tend to use the value 1). Then you can simply use IF DEFINED VARIABLE to test for TRUE or FALSE. One major advantage is you can set the value and test the result within a block of code without having to enable delayed expansion. One limitation of the IF DEFINED statement is it does not easily support variables with space in the name (see [What syntax will check if a variable name containing spaces is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8254571/1012053)).

You are explicitly looking for ERRORLEVEL 0 as success (found), and ERRORLEVEL 1 as failure (not found). I'm not aware of any other ERRORLEVEL that could be returned, and you don't bother handling any other value, so why not simply look for ERRORLEVEL 0 as success and treat any other value as failure?

Better yet, you can use the `&&` operator to conditionally run a block of commands upon success, and `||` to conditionally run a block of commands upon failure.

The security groups can have spaces in the name. Such a name would fail with your code. It would be better to use the FINDSTR /C option to specify the search string. The string must be enclosed in quotes if it contains spaces. The /C option treats the string as a literal by default, so no need for the /L option.

So here is how I would write your original code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cls
set "file=%temp%\gpresult%random%.txt"
gpresult /r /scope user >"%file%"
for %%i in (SysteemBeheer Administratie PersoneelsZaken TeamPlan "Group with space") do (
  findstr /i /c:%%i "%file%" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo Group %%i OK
  ) || (
    echo Group %%i Not Found
  )
)
del "%file%"
pause
```

If you want to set and test "boolean" variables, and you know that the names will never contain spaces, then I would use the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cls
set "file=%temp%\gpresult%random%.txt"
gpresult /r /scope user >"%file%"
for %%i in (SysteemBeheer Administratie PersoneelsZaken TeamPlan) do (
  set "GPO_%%i="
  findstr /i /l %%i "%file%" >nul 2>&1 && set "GPO_%%i=1"
)
del "%file%"

if defined GPO_systeemBeheer (Echo GPO_SysteemBeheer Found) else Echo GPO_SysteemBeheer Not Found!
if defined GPO_Administratie (Echo GPO_Administratie Found) else Echo GPO_Administratie Not Found!
if defined GPO_PersoneelsZaken (Echo GPO_PersoneelsZaken Found) else Echo GPO_PersoneelsZaken Not Found!
if defined GPO_TeamPlan (Echo GPO_TeamPlan Found) else Echo GPO_TeamPlan Not Found!
pause
```

If a group name can contain spaces then I would revert the IF test to something more like your 2nd set of code. If you use values of TRUE and FALSE instead of undefined and 1 then you can get rid of the enclosing quotes in the IF statement.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cls
set "file=%temp%\gpresult%random%.txt"
gpresult /r /scope user >"%file%"
for %%i in (SysteemBeheer Administratie PersoneelsZaken TeamPlan "Group with spaces") do (
  set "GPO_%%i="
  findstr /i /c:%%i "%file%" >nul 2>&1 && set "GPO_%%i=1"
)
del "%file%"

if "%GPO_systeemBeheer%"=="1" (Echo GPO_SysteemBeheer Found) else Echo GPO_SysteemBeheer Not Found!
if "%GPO_Administratie%"=="1" (Echo GPO_Administratie Found) else Echo GPO_Administratie Not Found!
if "%GPO_PersoneelsZaken%"=="1" (Echo GPO_PersoneelsZaken Found) else Echo GPO_PersoneelsZaken Not Found!
if "%GPO_TeamPlan%"=="1" (Echo GPO_TeamPlan Found) else Echo GPO_TeamPlan Not Found!
if "%GPO_Group with spaces%"=="1" (Echo GPO_Group with spaces Found) else Echo GPO_Group with spaces Not Found!
pause
```