# Set variable different values depending on IF ELSE condition in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

My goal is to set %PF% variable to C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\ on x64 machines and to C:\ProgramFiles\MSBuild\ on x86 machines.
I can easily achieve that such way

```
IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) SET PF=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\
IF NOT DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) SET PF=%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\
```

But I want to do that in a single IF ELSE statement.

That one

```
IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (SET PF=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\) ELSE (SET PF=%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\)
```

fails with ***unexpected "\MSBuild\"*** error.

That one

```
IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (SET PF="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\") ELSE (SET "PF=%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\")
```

runs without errors.

But the result value is not what I need (**"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\"** - instead of **"C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\"** on x64 machine for example).

So is that possibe?

Comment: Currently you can solve your problem with the answer of Stephan, but when you embedd your code into a code block you should also read [SO: What syntax will check if a variable name containing spaces is defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254571/what-syntax-will-check-if-a-variable-name-containing-spaces-is-defined), as you will get problems with the closing bracket in `if defined ProgramFiles(x86)`

Comment: Thx for that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this syntax:

```
SET "PF=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\"
```

Note the position of the quotes.